# If statement logic - array of objects

Tags: c++, if-statement

This takes place inside two loops with loop indices `i` and `j`.

`i` represents the object being examined and `j` is the arrays that are containing the top five numshares and the associated buyer name in another array. This is part of an assignment so I am fairly bound to this structure.

- `tArray`: an array of objects that contains `numShares` and `buyerName` as properties for each object.
- `calcstring`: contains the buyer name
- `calctotal`: contains the buyer names amount of shares (`numshares`)

I am finding the five buyers' names that have the highest numshares and storing them 1. [0] to 5. [4]

However when stepping through the program I realized that say `numshares` is higher than `calctotal[1]` on an iteration instead of pushing each element down the array and inserting `numshares`

the line `calctotal[j+1] = tVar` just replaces `calctotal[2]` instead of moving `calctotal[2]` down to `calctotal[3]` and so on

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

I should say again, I cannot use vectors etc

```
if(tArray[i].numShares > calcTotal[j])
{
    int tVar = calcTotal[j];
    string tStr = calcString[j];

    calcTotal[j+1] = tVar;                  
    calcString[j+1] = tStr;

    calcTotal[j] = tArray[i].numShares;
    calcString[j] = tArray[i].buyerName;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shift everything in the array down, you need to loop from the bottom up and assign each element in the array that comes after element j to the value of the element before it. If j is 4 when it gets to this loop, there won't be anything to shift down, so it won't do anything and calcTotal[4] will simply be overwritten.

```
if(tArray[i].numShares > calcTotal[j])
{
    for (int k = 4; k > j; k--) {
        calcTotal[k] = calcTotal[k - 1];
        calcString[k] = calcString[k - 1];
    }

    calcTotal[j] = tArray[i].numShares;
    calcString[j] = tArray[i].buyerName;
    break;
}
```